# What's the best way (in Android dev) to consume REST API (in addition to Retrofit)?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I quite new in Android developing platform (I'm frontender who has been using jQuery and now Angular2 (for 5 months) with RxJs ).
I used to code in core-Java in past for one year (6 years ago), so I'm little familiar with Java.

As I'm familiar with consuming REST API by using jQuery/Angular2 (which is really easy thing) I was wondering if there is any Android-framework to do that, or my only option is Retrofit, because I found it tangled to use.

Comment: retrofit is actually pretty easy and its being used in the combination with rxjava. you can check other popular libraries on android here https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/top-5-android-libraries-every-android-developer-should-know-about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Retrofit** is your best choice if you want a direct mapping between api endpoints and Java Objects. You simply create DTOs and annotate each field with the corresponding json name.

Depending on the size and purpose of the api you may want to have a deeper control over what you send and receive, i.e. direct access to `Request` and `Response` objects. in this case, I recommend **Volley** library :-)

Comment: *Retrofit is your best choice* that is a bit opinion based, don't you think? It's just one of the 1000 options

Answer (score 0):

1) Retrofit use for best way coz its internally used OK HTTP .
2) Volley Used but retrofit is much better .
3) Client -server communication purpose made own HTTP Code .